# Craft 2 White Screen - All Queries Not Running

Tags: query, craft2, logs, white-screen

I have a CraftCMS 2 template with a JavaScript setTimeout for auto refresh, and quite randomly, the page will only display a white page.

Dev mode is enabled, and, through the browser's inspector, in looking at the console log, I see that it usually gets only through 3 of the 23 queries when it does fail.

In troubleshooting this problem, are there certain problematic points to look out for in the logs?

This is the 'profiling summary report' in Firefox:

```
Time:   129.42611s
bulletin:49:10
Memory: 6,245Kb
bulletin:50:10
Total Queries: 3
bulletin:51:10
 count   total   average    min      max   bulletin:52:10
    1  0.00239  0.00239  0.00239  0.00239 system.db.CDbCommand.query(SHOW TABLES LIKE 'craft_%') bulletin:54:11  
    1  0.00031  0.00031  0.00031  0.00031 system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT `locale`
FROM `craft_locales`
ORDER BY `sortOrder`) bulletin:55:10
    1  0.00019  0.00019  0.00019  0.00019
system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT * FROM `craft_info` LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Update to the latest craftcms version first